# How to insert incoming e-mail message into mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, email

Just to say... I have no idea how would I do this :).

In other words, the thing is: You get a mail message from some guy pinky@pinky.com, you make a reply with your own content, and pinky@pinky.com have your reply stored in his database.

Additional:
I use shared hosting, I code in PHP, I understand ASP. If you have an idea how to write this script in another language, don't bother explaining me, because I won't understand anything.

A link to a solution is also welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is some kind of service, i don't think this is possible on shared hosting, you'll need more privileges.

Comment: This is a FAQ try searching SO for the many previous answers.

Answer (score 8):

So  
- you have a server
- you get emails
- you want to save them int a mysql database

**Cpanel config**

- go to cpnal email forwarder
- add a new one 
- redirect to PATH -> /home/your_user/whatever/php.script.php

**Php script**
(you may need to change the "/usr/bin/php -q" path depending on your server configuration)

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

if(strlen($email)<1) {
    die(); 
}

// handle email
$lines = explode("\n", $email);

// empty vars
$from = "";
$to="";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$splittingheaders = true;

for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if ($splittingheaders) {
        // this is a header
        $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";
        // look out for special headers
        if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $subject = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $from = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $to = $matches[1];
        }
    } else {
        // not a header, but message
        $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
    }
    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
        // empty line, header section has ended
        $splittingheaders = false;
    }
}
```

Works on shared hosting too! :)
All you need to add is the mysql insert and use the above-defined variables. Do you know how to use a mysql database from php? Or do you need help with that too?

Comment: Just this part I am confused on: `- go to cpnal email forwarder` I use Nginx web server with Ubuntu - any suggestions for me??

Comment: what mail server software / service are you using ?

Comment: At the moment nothing. I am using Sendgrid the SMTP server mainly and also SwiftMailer - Nginx for Server HTTP - no control panel it is all hard core...

Comment: Hi, im have done the mysql insert correctly but cant seem to clean uop the email body before i insert. I just want the body with all headers and attachments stripped. Just simple text with line breaks or paragraphs recgonised. How do i go about achieiving this? did you work yours out? sorry for the late post

Comment: Will this work if you forward MX records to the script itself? @vladb.

Comment: MX records, AFAIK, point to an email server. The email server you're using should have an option to send the new emails to a script. The MX records points to the server (ip, domain), not the script.