# Php - Message to Email Address, retrieved and stored in MySQL Database

Tags: php

I'm working on a system where, if a customer submits an order, they get a confirmation email.  However, I'd like to make the following happen.  if the customer then hits reply, and replies to this email address, I want their message to not go to that email address, but rather be stored in a MySQL database on the server.

Is there a way to 'intercept' and email in this way?

Comment: Depends on your host, my host (Bluehost) allows me to set up an email address that when messages come in a script handles them. Look through your CPanel or contact support to see if they offer something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have the reply to address set up to go straight into a mailbox that you can access using PHP's [imap_open](http://au.php.net/imap_open) to access and *read* emails. Armed with that, it should be a simple matter to insert the data as required into a database.

```
<?php
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.example.org:143}", "username", "password");

echo "<h1>Mailboxes</h1>\n";
$folders = imap_listmailbox($mbox, "{imap.example.org:143}", "*");

if ($folders == false) {
    echo "Call failed<br />\n";
} else {
    foreach ($folders as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}

echo "<h1>Headers in INBOX</h1>\n";
$headers = imap_headers($mbox);

if ($headers == false) {
    echo "Call failed<br />\n";
} else {
    foreach ($headers as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}

imap_close($mbox);
?>
```

The full list of [PHP IMAP functions](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) is very thorough.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a possible way directly without a mail box.

But you can do a special mailbox for that and fetch emails to `imap_*` functions from PHP and based on the `subject` or `email` to save them in database and then delete that email.

Answer (score 1):

Using [PHP IMAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) functions you can read in the mails sent to a specific address. You can't however make it not send to that address. But you can use the mail, put it in the database and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do that easily. What you can do is have a reply-to header in your email and send it to a monitored mailbox that a daemon-type service would periodically check for new emails and do its work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check following link and resources:

1. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html
2. http://code.google.com/p/php-imap

Or you can follow this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468937/how-to-insert-incoming-e-mail-message-into-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Have a look here: http://www.mddhosting.com/support/knowledgebase/1011/Email-Piping-to-a-PHP-Script-in-cPanel-x3-Theme.html

and another one: http://harrybailey.com/2009/02/send-or-pipe-an-email-to-a-php-script/