# Parsing Email with >Forward on cPanel

Tags: php, email, parsing

I'm trying to use this [E-mail parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469203/2253323) on my VPS with cPanel.

I have forwarded incoming emails to my script but I get an error emailed back at me:

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

 pipe to |/home/../parser_3.php
   generated by domain.tld
   local delivery failed

The following text was generated during the delivery attempt:

------ pipe to |/home/../parser_3.php
      generated by test3@domain.tld ------

Could not exec '/home/../parser_3.php'
Reporting-MTA: dos; domain.tld

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;|/home/../parser_3.php
Status: 5.0.0
```

Since I have used the script as it is, I am thinking maybe I need to install some php package to get it to work?

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

if(strlen($email)<1) {
    die(); 
}

// handle email
$lines = explode("\n", $email);

// empty vars
$from = "";
$to="";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$splittingheaders = true;

for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if ($splittingheaders) {
        // this is a header
        $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";
        // look out for special headers
        if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $subject = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $from = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $to = $matches[1];
        }
    } else {
        // not a header, but message
        $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
    }
    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
        // empty line, header section has ended
        $splittingheaders = false;
    }
}


$to = $unprocessed_email;

                $subject = 'TEST PARSER 3 - '.$date = date('md his', time()).'';

                $message = '<br><br> From: '. $from .' <br><br> To: '. $to .' <br><br> Subject: '. $subject .' <br><br> Headers: '. $headers .' <br><br> Message: '. $message .' <br><br><br>'.  print_r( $email, true ) .'';

                $headers = 'From: "Email-Parser" <parser@domain.tld>' . "\r\n" .

                           'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
                           'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n".

                           'X-Mailer: PHPv: '.phpversion() . "\r\n" .


'';

                $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


     if ($result) echo 'Mail accepted for delivery ';
     if (!$result) echo 'Test unsuccessful... '
```

Or maybe it doesn't work at all on PHP 7?

---

The outcome would be to parse incoming emails. And shoot them over to my email. And later on add the to a database, assuming I get the parsing working.

Comment: The error message you're getting is `Could not exec '/home/home/../parser_3.php'` - it looks like you're pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: @andrewsi I was changing the names of the directories before I posted, so I don't expose my domain.

Comment: When I run `parser_3.php` in the browser, even the email script won't run...when I run it alone it runs just fine.

Comment: When you try to run it in the browser, what happens? Bear in mind you're reading from stdin, so it might just hang waiting for input that never arrives.... Can you run it from the command line?

Comment: In the browser I get a bank screen. So theres a problem before the email gets sent out, otherwise I should see `if ($result) echo `. No clue how to run it from the command line. If you know what command I should run, I'll try it @andrewsi